# CentOS running RabbitMQ failed to create a trace file and log on other vhost remotely

Tags: linux, rabbitmq

We have installed and run RabbitMQ on a CentOS server. Although it is OK to create a trace file using Firehose tracer from the management console on another computer remotely in the vhost that is under permission ofthe guest user, it is failed to create the same log file remotely in the other vhosts which are not under permission of the guest user.

For instance, in the figure below, we simply create the testLogTracer on the test vhost but it is failed to create the same log file testLogTracer2 on test2 vhost. The only difference between the two vhosts is that the guest user has permission over the test vhost.

[image]

Update:

The latest server error which is added to the file rabbit@server79.log at the time of creating the trace file represented below:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 26-Jan-2016::13:13:19 ===
webmachine error: path="/api/traces/hafizTest/newTraceFile"
"Bad Request"
```

Also user "moha" has full permission like user "guest" over both vhost "test" and "test2". The permission over both virtual hosts represented in figures below.

[image: user permission over vhost "test"]
[image: user permission over vhost "test2"]

Comment: `gues` user is valid only in localhost ! try with another user

Comment: @Gabriele I know what you said. But it is a different situation. I can't create a log file remotely in order to trace messages in a specified vhost, unless guest user has permission over that vhost.

Comment: Could you post the server log?

Comment: It is the only error which is added to the file rabbit@server79.log in Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have asked my question in [github](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tracing/issues/1) and [RabbitMQ-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/Le0goGbkDCM) group and thank you to Micheal Klishin who answered my quesion.

Before RabbitMq 3.6.0, the only user that can create a trace file over a virtual host remotely was guest user. Fortunately, in the latest version (e.g. 3.6.0) other user can create a trace file over a virtual host by adding `rabbitmq_tracing.username` and `rabbitmq_tracing.password` to the rabbitmq.config file.

This file is not available in the installation time and you should add it in the directory `/etc/rabbitmq` by yourself. One can simply add the lines below to the config file in order to change the default user (e.g. guest) for creating trace file over RabbitMQ.

```
{rabbitmq_tracing, 
    [{username, "user"},
     {password, "pass"}]
 },
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems a permission problem.

Please read this post: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/uA9qmADgpSo/Cib3fEFwDgAJ

> Please check the permission on your virtualhost, this error can
>   happens if you don't have the right permission.
>
> here is and example:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 4-Jan-2016::15:49:38 ===
Adding vhost 'myvhost'

=INFO REPORT==== 4-Jan-2016::15:49:57 ===
Enabling tracing for vhost 'myvhost'

=ERROR REPORT==== 4-Jan-2016::15:49:57 ===
webmachine error: path="/api/traces/myvhost/myvhostlog"
"Bad Request"

=INFO REPORT==== 4-Jan-2016::15:50:04 ===
Setting permissions for 'guest' in 'myvhost' to '.*', '.*', '.*'

=INFO REPORT==== 4-Jan-2016::15:50:08 ===
Disabling tracing for vhost 'myvhost'

=INFO REPORT==== 4-Jan-2016::15:50:18 ===
Enabling tracing for vhost 'myvhost'

=INFO REPORT==== 4-Jan-2016::15:50:18 ===
Tracer opened log file "/var/tmp/rabbitmq-tracing/myvhostlog.log"

-
Gabriele
```

Comment: I have updated my question again, I want to know if it is mandatory to grant user guest all permissions over any virtual host?

Comment: Before the 3.6.0, Tracing connection has credentials hardcoded to "guest". 
Please read here:https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tracing/issues/1

Comment: Dear @Gabriele , tnx for your patience in advance,  I've checked the RabbitMQ version just right now and it is 3.6.0, so it shouldn't face this problem. It is obvious from the first screenshot attached to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly a reply, just adding a similar problem error message, to make easier for people searching for the error message. Sadly it is too big for a comment and do not want to add it directly to the question as it is not the original poster error message

```
2018-07-10 20:37:34 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
     Supervisor: {<0.11027.6>,rabbit_tracing_consumer_sup}
     Context:    start_error
     Reason:     {{badmatch,{error,not_allowed}},[{rabbit_tracing_consumer,init,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_tracing_consumer.erl"},{line,58}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,365}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,333}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
     Offender:   [{pid,undefined},{name,consumer},{mfargs,{rabbit_tracing_consumer,start_link,[[{vhost,<<"my_vhost">>},{name,<<"my_log_file">>},{format,<<"text">>},{pattern,<<"#">>},{<<"format">>,<<"text">>},{<<"name">>,<<"my_log_file">>},{<<"pattern">>,<<"#">>},{<<"vhost">>,<<"my_vhost">>}]]}},{restart_type,transient},{shutdown,30000},{child_type,worker}
```

The key parte is the `not_allowed`, pointing to a permission problem, in this case, `guest` user is **missing permissions** on that **vhost**